# running the camera plugin on cordova its showing error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

H:\Ionic apps\camera>ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save (exit code 1):

```
    Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-camera via registry.
    Probably this is either a connection problem or plugin spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

H:\Ionic apps\camera>cordova plugin list
No plugins added. Use `cordova plugin add <plugin>`.
{}'

Comment: what does `ionic info` give?

Answer (score 0):

you have used **ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera**
use this instead, dont't add ionic in the start

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

or

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```